# How can I debug INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK?

Tags: android, android-studio

I've gotten this error at various times in Android Studio. I see there are a lot of related questions, but the answers are mostly guess-answers such as "try cleaning and re-building" or "try deleting such and such tmp directory". Is there any way to get android studio to give me some error output so I can find out what's failing?

Comment: AndroidStudio usually show this kind of error under the View: Build after the task: install. Often this kind of error can be an error while updating the current application of the device, so the solution may be uninstall the application from the device and try installing trough AndroidStudio

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos, it's a system app on a rooted device, so I don't think there is a way to uninstall.

Comment: If it's a system app you didn't install probably the erro is that your project is signed with a keystore different from the one the application is installed in the device